# Is it possible to add the number of copies of a PDF file printed in the browser automatically?

Tags: javascript, printing

I tried to print a **pdf** file from the browser using the java script, I'm using the following code

```
this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: true,bShrinkToFit: false});
```

The file is printed silently to the default printer, my problem is that one copy of the file is printed, and I would like to print two copies, is there any method to set the number of copies?, and thank U in advance.

Comment: just do it twice there is no number of copies parameter according to this documentation http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_PrintProduction.75.3.html

Comment: It's not possible to do it that way, I'm using iReport to print so I add a property to the JRXML file, when I tray to do what U say, one copy is printed, so it's not work, but thank U at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to add number of copies using java script.